# Number of quadrilaterals

Tags: combinatorics

10 points lie in a plane,of which 4 points are collinear.Barring these 4 no three of the 10 points are collinear.How many distinct quadrilaterals can be drawn?                                                                         I tried:                                                                                ->                6 non collinear points form a quadrilateral that equals 6C4=15                                                              ->                 1 collinear of the 4 and 3 non collinear that equals 4C1*6C3=80                                                       ->                 2 collinear out of 4 and 2 non collinear that equals 6C2*4C2=90.Total comes to 185.Is any case left out as the answer is 209.Please help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Did you try something?

Comment: OP wrote "I tried $\cdots$".

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because we are never told to use only four points. In other words, we can make a quadrilateral which includes more than four points of yours. For example, there may be another point on an edge of the quadrilateral.

Comment: Oh i missed that

Comment: But be careful. Because some of which I mentioned may be already included as yours.

Comment: Yup.it striked me..im getting 209 now.

Comment: You are welcome.